# Есть ли какой-то API для доступа к камерам города (МСК, Тверь)

Tags: python, api, камера

Мне нужен api дающий доступ к камерам наблюдения в городах желательно МСК и Тверь, заранее спасибо (это не комерческий проект)

Comment: https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/0a8607713c152645dfeebca43023e52d36b6bb0a/ ;)

Comment: мои  цели не попадают по эту статью, я хотел видеть что происходит на дорогах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Как такового API я найти не смог, но вы можете подключаться к IP-камерам с помощью модуля OpenCv.**

Например - вот так:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.64/1')
```

Ссылка на источник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv

Comment: Спасибо, но как мне узнавать ip камер установленных в городе

Comment: Просто так IP камеры, которая установлена в вашем городе, вам скорее всего никто не даст. Вы конечно можете стараться искать IP камеры без логина и пароля в интернете, но успех вам не гарантирую. Это очень муторная тема.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - купить собственную IP камеру и установить её там, где нужно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вероятно сначала неправильно понял ваш вопрос. Если вы хотите подключаться к камерам не напрямую - используйте ту же функцию, но вместо URL камеры подставьте туда URL прямой трансляции с этой камеры в интернете.

Comment: Понял спасибо вам большое!